# Rank slow MySQL queries using elasticserach + kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, logstash, kibana

I'm puzzled by this problem: I've set a logstash instance reading from mysql_slow_query and already have some analysis running (like avg query time and lock time per user etc), but the most important thing is still missing: the query ranking. That is, what are the top slow queries - how many times they occur, what is their avg query time and so on.

You see, I'd paste here some of my tries, but I have no clue how to build a visualization in kibana which could count the selects, considering that the parameters of the WHERE clause are always changing.

What I need is something like this:

```
~~~ Example data
SELECT * FROM costumer WHERE city = 'London' and name = 'James';
SELECT * FROM costumer WHERE city = 'New York' and name = 'Will';
SELECT * FROM company WHERE name = 'Google';

~~~ Visualization needed (some sort of)
SELECT FROM costumer: 2 hits
SELECT FROM company: 1 hit
```

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Kibana, you can aggregate on a field and get the count.  It might be messy/useless if you have a lot of different queries.  It would work well for your example data, or you could pull out the initial table name into another field and aggregate on that.